# Is there and easy way to make responsive search result on text box to Data Grid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've part of program that have ordinary search function where user inputting data on textbox, it will display the result based on what user typing. Here's my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean find = false;
    if (cmbSearchFilter.Text == "Product Name")
    {
        int row = 0;
        string line, search;
        string[] strArray = new string[6];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Nugget ID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Nugget Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Nugget Description";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Nugget Ingredient";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Nugget Stock";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Nugget Price";
        F = new FileStream("Nugget.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        R = new StreamReader(F);
        search = txtSearch.Text;
        while ((line = R.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            strArray = line.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (search.Equals(strArray[1]))
            {
                find = true;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                String[] s = line.Split('#');
                for (int i = 0; i <= s.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1[i, row].Value = s[i];
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
        R.Close();
        F.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm using `IF` condition based on what user choosing in combobox. So there's no problem with the code and problem with this case.

Back to main problem, i want make the search result responsive, for instance if i've this data on text file:

```
Chicken Nugget
Cheese Nugget
Tofu Nugget
Vegetable Nugget
```

First when user typing 'C' word, the result on dgv will showing data Chicken Nugget and Cheese Nugget. Second, when typing 'h' (after 'C'), the result would showing Chicken Nugget and Cheese Nugget (again). Third, when typing 'e', (after 'Ch'), the result would showing only Cheese Nugget, and soon. So is there a simple code to solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, instead of loading the grid per keystroke, you can just do it once on form load. This code can be moved to your form load event:

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    int row = 0;
    string line;
    string[] strArray = new string[6];
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Nugget ID";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Nugget Name";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Nugget Description";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Nugget Ingredient";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Nugget Stock";
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Nugget Price";
    FileStream F = new FileStream("Nugget.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader R = new StreamReader(F);

    while ((line = R.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        strArray = line.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        String[] s = line.Split('#');
        for (int i = 0; i <= s.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1[i, row].Value = s[i];
        }
    }

    R.Close();
    F.Close();
}
```

To look for a section of text, you can use the string "Contains" method. Each string being compared can be converted to lowercase to make the comparison case insensitive. You can use the DataGridViewRow.Visible property to only show rows that match your search.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string search = txtSearch.Text;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["Nugget Name"].Value != null)
        {
            string productName = row.Cells["Nugget Name"].Value.ToString();
            row.Visible = productName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

F and R are not declared.
With each character you type in the textbox you recreate all the datagridview columns, open and read the file, and manually fill in the dgv.  I would probably create a list of strings at the class level to hold the file info and only fill that the first time if it is empty, then use that list as a datasource for the dgv.